# How do I use Yarn's `.pnp.js` file?

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-v2

Using Yarn 2, the default installation method creates a `.pnp.js` file (Plug'n'Play) instead of a `node_modules` directory.

How do I use this file to run my Node application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a Node application with Yarn's Plug'n'Play you must preload the `.pnp.js` file using the `--require` flag.

```
node --require ./.pnp.js foo.js
```

**Note**: Make sure that the `--require` path starts with `./` or `../`.

To start an ESM application, you also need to use the `--loader` flag (both flags are needed).

```
node --require ./.pnp.cjs --loader ./.pnp.loader.mjs foo.mjs
```